# Telerik mvc grid selected row color

Tags: telerik-grid

I have a Server binding Telerik MVC grid, I want to change the background color of the selected row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look a this page:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selectionserverside/BONAP?Customers-mode=select

Comment: I used the same technique but the problem that after page reload,at my upper grid , the selected row is not highlighted

Comment: You have to set one row as selected after reload,

Comment: @JAiro :  Many Thanks . The solution was that it works by default when i removed a row action that i was set

Comment: :), Great, so If you found the solution clouse the question, good luck.

Comment: @JAiro : How can I Clouse the Question :$ ?

Comment: you have to tick the correct answer under the points assigned to the answer on the left.